# Aggregation query in mongoDB and mongoTemplate

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have this mongo collection:

```
{
  "id" : String,
  "amount" : BigDecimal,
  "industry" : IndustryEnum
}
```

I want to use `mongoTemplate` to get all the documents of `industry`  `OIL`, and then put the results into lists in such a way that no document witht the same id is adjacent. Ideally I would like a map where each value is a list as shown below (omitting the `type` for space purposes):

```
  list 1: [[id::"AB", amount:: BigDecimal.valueOf(3300)], [id::"bB", amount:: BigDecimal.valueOf(2000)], [id::"cB", amount:: BigDecimal.valueOf(1400)]]
  list 2: [[id::"AB", amount:: BigDecimal.valueOf(1200)], [id::"bB", amount:: BigDecimal.valueOf(1002)], [id::"cB", amount:: BigDecimal.valueOf(1300)]]
  list 3: [[id::"AB", amount:: BigDecimal.valueOf(1000)], [id::"cB", amount:: BigDecimal.valueOf(1120)]]
```

I am really new in Mongo, and SQL, so I would really appreciate any help or pointers.

Comment: It is not clear to me what your required output is, do you mind either explaining further or give an example?. also what are those records you posted? why are we seeing duplicate records over and over?

Comment: This id is not unique, it can be the same in many documents. The final goal is to create a Map, with value List<type>. Each "id" can exist only once in a list. And also, in each list, the values are sorted starting with the one that has the highest "amount" value. I hope that this makes more sense.

Comment: Add please real sample with expected JSON output

Comment: Is each list a seperate query result?, if you have two matching `id` what is `amount`? sum? large of the two?

Comment: No, I want all the elements of IndustryEnum "OIL" and then, these should be taxonomized into a Map with value List<CollectionObject>. If they have same id they need to be in different list